# Why doesn't overflow auto not working in div element?

Tags: html, css, arduino-ide

I am currently developing `html` site, where I embed exported `html` code from Arduino.
I tried to add `overflow: auto;` to stylesheet file, it doesn't work – it couldn't be scrolled to side on narrow screens, but instead it wraps...

Here is my code:

```css
body {
    margin: 5% 20%;
}

.code {
    padding: 0.5em;
    background-color: #282c34;
    counter-reset: line;
    font-family: 'Hack', monospace;
    overflow: auto;
}

.code div::before {
    counter-increment: line;
    content: counter(line);
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0em 0.5em 0em 0em;
    width: 2em;
    color: #555555;
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="code">
        <div><span style="color: #98c379;">#include</span> <span style="color: #aaaaaa;">&lt;</span><span
                style="color: #e06c75; font-weight: bold;">EEPROM</span><span style="color: #aaaaaa;">.</span><span style="color: #ffffff;">h</span><span
                style="color: #aaaaaa;">&gt;</span></div>
        <div><span style="color: #98c379;">#include</span> <span style="color: #aaaaaa;">&lt;</span><span
                style="color: #e06c75; font-weight: bold;">Servo</span><span style="color: #aaaaaa;">.</span><span style="color: #ffffff;">h</span><span
                style="color: #aaaaaa;">&gt;</span></div>
        <div><span style="color: #e06c75; font-weight: bold;">Servo</span> <span style="color: #ffffff;">s1</span><span style="color: #ffffff;">;</span></div>
        <div><span style="color: #e06c75; font-weight: bold;">Servo</span> <span style="color: #ffffff;">s2</span><span style="color: #ffffff;">;</span></div>
        <div></div>
        <div><span style="color: #98c379;">#define</span> <span style="color: #ffffff;">sensor</span> <span style="color: #ffffff;">A0</span></div>
        <div><span style="color: #98c379;">#define</span> <span style="color: #ffffff;">IR</span> <span style="color: #e5c07b;">3</span></div>
        <div></div>
        <div><span style="color: #61afef;">int</span> <span style="color: #ffffff;">x</span> <span style="color: #aaaaaa;">=</span> <span
                style="color: #e5c07b;">100</span><span style="color: #ffffff;">;</span> <span style="color: #aaaaaa;">&#47;&#47;count of
                measurements</span></div>
        <div><span style="color: #61afef;">String</span> <span style="color: #ffffff;">color</span><span style="color: #ffffff;">;</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your code snippet isn't quite minimal; the vast majority of that code isn't pertinent to the problem you're facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overflow really only makes sense on elements that:

- have `display` 'block' or 'inline-block'
- have an explicit width (or height, depending on the nature of overflow) set

Additionally, where the overflow is text that you don't want to wrap, you also need to give `white-space: nowrap`.

Your element lacks all of these factors. So:

```
.code {
    display: block; /* or inline-block; }
    width: 200px; /* or 100%, or whatever */
    white-space: nowrap;
    /* other styles */
}
```

Comment: I tried it and there is only `white-space: nowrap;` needed. But also thanks for explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

div {white-space: nowrap}